Joining AD LDS servers to another domain
We are trying to join 6 of our AD LDS servers to another domain. There is a one way trust relationship between the domains. All necessary ports are open (i.e., 386 and 636). What would be the best way to join them without breaking the replication? I tried joining one of them and getting the following error "Error contacting server  (network error) -2146893022 (0x80090322)
: The target principal name is incorrect".
When I run the syncall after joining one of the AD LDS servers to the new domain, I get the following error "Error contacting server  (network error): 1722 (8x6ba)"
I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this.

Error contacting server (network error): 1722 that usually means that the truckload of ports are not open between the source and destination. At a minimum that would be 135 and 49152-65535 for RPC.
